# Nagios plugin not working from server but Locally

Tags: bash, monitoring, docker, nagios, containers

I have written a small bash script which checks whether docker service is functioning or not and it's quite fine when I test on client locally but somehow it's not working from nagios server which actually use `check_nrpe` to execute my script, It always shows else part of script. my nrpe.cfg is correct too.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

CONTAINER=ubuntu_container

RUNNING=$(docker inspect --format="{{ .State.Running }}" $CONTAINER 2> /dev/null)

if [ "$RUNNING" == "true" ]; then
   echo "OK - $CONTAINER is running."
   exit  0
else
   echo "CRITICAL - $CONTAINER is not running."
   exit 2
fi
```

Output from nagios server:

```
root@nag_server nagios]# /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -t 30 -H docker-host.intenallab -c docker_container
CRITICAL - ubuntu_container is not running.
```

Output from Client:

```
[root@ubuntu]# /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/extra/docker_container 
OK - ubuntu_container is running.
```

Comment: How did you call the script from nrpe? Show us the relevant config line from `nrpe.cfg`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a permission error. You are running the script locally as root user while you are running the script remotely via nrpe as nagios user (you did not show us the relevant `nrpe.cfg` config line that calls the script).

To fix this, you can modify nrpe.cfg file to looks like:

```
command[docker_container]=sudo /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/extra/docker_container
```

Also, don't forget to add nagios user to sudoers file to execute this script without asking for a password using `visudo`.

Answer (score 0):

It is a permissions issue as @Khaled pointed out, but I wasn't able to get that solution to work.  Adding the user to the docker group did the trick for me.

```
sudo usermod -a -G docker $(grep nrpe_user /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg|awk -F= '{print $2}')
```

After that my user is able to run docker commands without the need for sudo and NRPE completes successfully from the Nagios server.